# f# overwrite array access operator .[]

Tags: f#

in F#, I  want to make a type of indexed array, so I can access the element by either `.[i]` or `.[index_names]` and by slice notation with index `..` Is it possible to overwrite `.[]` like this? thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

define overloaded indexer in your type:

```
type MyIndexedArray<'T>() = 
    member this.Item(i : int) : 'T = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
    member this.Item(name : string) : 'T = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
    member this.GetSlice(a : int option, b : int option) : 'T = Unchecked.defaultof<_>

let arr = new MyIndexedArray<int>()
let a = arr.[1]
let b = arr.["name"]
let c = arr.[1..2]
let d = arr.[1..]
let e = arr.[..3]
let f = arr.[*]
```